# How to implement message output in QMessage using function call when pressing the QPushButton?

Tags: c++, qt

Faced with the following task at the interview:

In this task you need to create a simple user interface (UI) with QtWidgets and connect it to the supplied library. ComboBox must contain three items. When the current item changes - the button also changes. Depending on the button, you have to call corresponding function from the library and show its
output in the message. Thus, each button shows a different message.

[image]

I did 2/3 of task but I can’t figure out how to implement a task with buttons and display a message in QMessage by calling a function.

A header file was attached to the task, which included prototypes of the three functions string getFunction1(), string getFunction2(), string getFunction3() and also the .dll library.

I would be very grateful for the clarification of how best to implement the task.

Comment: Could you please show us your 2/3 completion? From there on it will be much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing:

1. Create a `QComboBox` on the Designer and initialize it with items as 
   required in the `QWidget` constructor.

   ```
   Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
   QWidget(parent),
   ui(new Ui::Widget)
    {
     ui->setupUi(this);
     ui->comboBox->addItem("first");
     ui->comboBox->addItem("second");
     ui->comboBox->addItem("third");
     ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(0);
     ui->pushButton->setText("first");//because of the combox's current index is zero, 
                                        thus "first";
   }
   ```
2. Create a `QPushButton`on the Designer and it got initialized in the constructor above with the text.
3. Right click on `QComboBox` of the designer and click on `Goto slot` and select slot `on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)` and click ok.
4. Inside slot `on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)`
   add the statement  `ui->pushButton->setText(arg1);` //this is because if user click on another option on the combobox and we should update the button's text.

   ```
   void Widget::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)
   {
     ui->pushButton->setText(arg1);//updating the button's text.
   }
   ```
5. Right click on `QPushButton` of the designer and click on `Goto slot` and select slot `on_pushButton_clicked()` and click ok.
6. Inside the slot `on_pushButton_clicked()` have this code and call the corresponding the dll function according to button's text.

   ```
    void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
      if(ui->pushButton->text()=="first")
    {
       //call getFunction1() and assign the return value to QString msg
       QString msg;
       QMessageBox::about(this,"called function return value",msg);//showing in the msgbox.

    }
     else if(ui->pushButton->text()=="second")
     {
       //call getFunction2() and assign the return value to QString msg
       QString msg;
       QMessageBox::about(this,"called function return value",msg);
     }
     else
     {
       //call getFunction3() and assign the return value to QString msg
       QString msg;
       QMessageBox::about(this,"called function return value",msg);
     }
   }
   ```